# Http request parameter type propagation

Tags: java, http, rest, web-applications

I have a simple web app which propagates requests to another web app. My web app provides two very similar API's which query the same web app but for different types of information. For instance, my web app takes these two URL's

[http://myservice.com:8080/otherservicecall1?userId=(userid)](http://myservice.com:8080/otherservicecall1?userId=%28userid%29)

[http://myservice.com:8080/otherservicecall2?accountId=(accountid)](http://myservice.com:8080/otherservicecall2?accountId=%28accountid%29)

If I want to use the same service and data layer for my web app, what is the best way to differentiate between the two different parameters for these requests? For instance, I have a class in my data layer which handles 404's from the other service, with log messages such as

```
log.error("Could not find information on userId = " + userId);
```

But logs and exception messages like this are not generic enough to apply to both types of requests, meaning I have to pass in a parameter type variable which just holds the name of the parameter.

I guess what I'm ultimately asking is, is there a simple way to propagate the name of the parameter that I'm passing in through the controller through the service and data layer without passing it in through every function call? I have thought of making use of enumerations somehow but I can't see how they would help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exceptions, We throw a generic ObjectNotFoundException that has a method that will return the id of an object we're looking for.  If we need specialized exception messages we will extend our ObjectNotFoundException with something more specific and then update our Spring SimpleMappingExceptionResolver to handle the new, more specific, exception.

We make sure to keep the most general exception (ObjectNotFoundException) last in the exceptionMapping list.

For services, well, I wouldn't worry about if the parameter is called userid or accountid.  The behavior for both those parameters should be the same.  If you are worried about it, then your user interface layer is bleeding into your service and persistence layers;  Which, is a bad thing.

Comment: I do use @RequestMapping. I have two separate functions in my controller to handle the two requests. My question is moreover a java question than a spring implementation question. I want to know the best way to propagate the name of the request parameter through classes without just passing it along through functions.